# Issue with my Check Box in PyQt and Python

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt4

I have a checkbox named "selectAllCheckBox". When this in checked state, all the checkboxes(created dynamically) inside the listview should change to checked state and when "selectAllCheckBox" checkbox is in Unchecked state, all the dynamically created checkboxes should change to unchecked state.

```
self.dlg.selectAllCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.selectAll)
def selectAll(self):
    """Select All layers loaded inside the listView"""

    model = self.dlg.DatacheckerListView1.model()
    for index in range(model.rowCount()):
        item = model.item(index)
        if item.isCheckable() and item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

What the above code does it makes  the dynamic checkboxes inside the listview to Checked state even when "SelectAllCheckBox" is in Unchecked state. Please help me how to solve this using python. Is there anything could be done in signal like when the checkbox is "checked" or "unchecked" to connect to a slot instead of stateChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [stateChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged) signal sends the [checked state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CheckState-enum), so the slot could be re-written as:

```
def selectAll(self, state=QtCore.Qt.Checked):
    """Select All layers loaded inside the listView"""

    model = self.dlg.selectAllCheckBox.model()
    for index in range(model.rowCount()):
        item = model.item(index)
        if item.isCheckable():
            item.setCheckState(state)
```

(NB: if all the rows in the list-view have checkboxes, the `isCheckable` line could be omitted)

Comment: Code works perfectly. But the difference between mine and yours is you had passed the state as an argument in the method. So could you please make it clear still? what is your code doing now?

Comment: @harinish. I gave the `state` argument a default value so that `selectAll` can be called with no arguments. When `selectAll` is connected to a signal that sends the state, the default argument will just be overridden.

Comment: My question is what is the default state of the "stateChanged()" signal.? And also stateChanged will be called both when the selectAllCheckBox is checked and unchecked by the user. So if selectAll is checked it will call the method "selectAll" and change the state to "Checked". But how it is unchecking all the dynamic checkboxes when the selectAll checkbox is unchecked? We didn't set any state like "Unchecked" in our method right? And also the stateChanged() signal works without passing any argument. But in http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged it was asked to pass an argument

Comment: The `stateChanged` signal has no default state. Whenever a checkbox is checked or unchecked by the user, it emits a signal that sends its *current* checked-state. Signals are not functions: see [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) for more details.