# Creating a toggling "Check All" checkbox for a ListView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a ListView full of checkable items. I want to place a tristate "check all" checkbox above the ListView, and I want this checkbox to be bi-directional.

That is, if the user toggles the check all checkbox, I want all of the ListView's items to mirror the check all's selection. But if the user manually checks or unchecks items in the ListView, I want the select all checkbox to reflect that state (i.e. checked if all of the ListView items are checked, unchecked if they are all unchecked, or partially checked if some of the ListView items are checked).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142987/issue-with-my-check-box-in-pyqt-and-python) shows how to wire the first part (checking/unchecking the select all box propagates its state to the list view's items). However, I'm stumped as to how wire the other direction.

This is how I'm getting the Check All checkbox to propagate to the ListView:

```
self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

self.select_all_cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Check All', self.ui.tab)
self.select_all_cb.setChecked(True)
self.select_all_cb.setStyleSheet('margin-left: 5px; font: bold')
self.select_all_cb.stateChanged.connect(self.selectAllCheckChanged)
self.layout.addWidget(select_all_cb)

self.listview = QtGui.QListView(self.ui.tab)
self.listview.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.listview.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.listview.setSelectionRectVisible(False)

model = QStandardItemModel()
for checkItem in self.checkItems:
    item = QStandardItem(checkItem)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    item.setSelectable(False)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
    model.appendRow(item)
self.listview.setModel(model)
self.layout.addWidget(listview)


def selectAllCheckChanged(self):
    model = self.listview.model()
    for index in range(model.rowCount()):
        item = model.item(index)
        if item.isCheckable():
            if self.select_all_cb.isChecked():
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            else:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

Any suggestions on how to go the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to the `itemChanged` signal on the `QStandardItemModel` and test the state of all the checkboxes.

```
from itertools import product

self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.test_check)

def test_check(self, item):
    items = [self.model.item(r,c) for r, c in product(range(self.model.rowCount()), range(self.model.columnCount())]

    if all(item.checkState() == Qt.Checked for item in items)
        state = Qt.Checked
    elif any(item.checkState() == Qt.Checked for item in items):
        state = Qt.PartiallyChecked
    else:
        state = Qt.Unchecked

    if self.select_all_cb.checkState() != state:
        self.select_all_cb.setCheckState(state)
```

If you have a very large number of checkboxes, you may be able to optimize this by caching the check state of each item and updating the cache whenever the item state changes, and then checking the cache instead of pulling it from each item every time.

If you know you're going to be making changes to many items at once, you should probably blockSignals on the model and then run this function manually after making all the changes.

In your `selectAllCheckChanged` handler, you should also block signals on the model so it doesn't trigger this handler

```
def selectAllCheckChanged(self):
    model = self.listview.model()
    model.blockSignals(True)
    try:
        for index in range(model.rowCount()):
            item = model.item(index)
            if item.isCheckable():
                if self.select_all_cb.isChecked():
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
                else:
                    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    finally:
        model.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. The only issue is that the select all checkbox cycles through the partial state. I got around this by calling `.setTristate(False)` whenever the checkbox was checked or unchecked, and only `.setTristate(True)` when it needed to be set to the partial check state.

Answer (score 1):

In case it will help others, here's how I incorporated Brendan's answer in my code. The differences are the tristate functionality is enabled only when needed (so the user can't enable the partial-checked state), and I wired it with the `clicked` signal instead of `stateChange` to avoid `selectAllCheckChanged` from being triggered by `listviewCheckChanged`. The `model.blockSignals` works too, of course, but using `clicked` seemed more pythonic to me.

```
self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

self.select_all_cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Check All', self.ui.tab)
self.select_all_cb.setTristate(False) # Only enable tristate when necessary so the user doesn't click it through to partially checked
self.select_all_cb.setChecked(True)
self.select_all_cb.setStyleSheet('margin-left: 5px; font: bold')
self.select_all_cb.clicked.connect(self.selectAllCheckChanged) # clicked instead of stateChanged so this doesn't get triggered by ListView's changes
self.layout.addWidget(select_all_cb)

self.listview = QtGui.QListView(self.ui.tab)
self.listview.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.listview.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.listview.setSelectionRectVisible(False)

model = QStandardItemModel()
for checkItem in self.checkItems:
    item = QStandardItem(checkItem)
    item.setCheckable(True)
    item.setSelectable(False)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
    model.appendRow(item)
self.listview.setModel(model)
self.listview.clicked.connect(self.listviewCheckChanged)
self.layout.addWidget(listview)


def selectAllCheckChanged(self):
    ''' updates the listview based on select all checkbox '''
    model = self.listview.model()
    for index in range(model.rowCount()):
        item = model.item(index)
        if item.isCheckable():
            if self.select_all_cb.isChecked():
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            else:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

def listviewCheckChanged(self):
    ''' updates the select all checkbox based on the listview '''
    model = self.listview.model()
    items = [model.item(index) for index in range(model.rowCount())]

    if all(item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked for item in items):
        self.select_all_cb.setTristate(False)
        self.select_all_cb.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
    elif any(item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked for item in items):
        self.select_all_cb.setTristate(True)
        self.select_all_cb.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)
    else:
        self.select_all_cb.setTristate(False)
        self.select_all_cb.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```